# JDBC Connector Stage generates wrong datatype "name" in DDL for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, ddl, datastage

When generating a ceate statement using a **JDBC Stage** on a **ProstgreSQL database**, instead of the **expected data types** `varchar(n)` or `text`, the datatype **`name(n)`** is used, so the generated ddl will not function.

The datatype `name` (without `(n)`) is actually an *"internal type for object names but not intended for general-purpose use, only for use in the internal system catalogs"*, [as documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html).

When running the datasatge job, the Connector finds following driver information: `The driver name and version are: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.6.0`, `The data source name and version are: PostgreSQL 15.3 (15.3)`.

The Job aborts with the message '*[SQLSTATE 42601] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type modifier is not allowed for type "name"*', which

I made test job which should create a table and write to it. It generates a ddl for the corresponding DataStage data types, but the it is wrong:

```sql
CREATE TABLE
    myschema.my_test_table
    (
        this_is_int int4 NOT NULL,
        this_is_char CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        this_is_varchar name(10) NOT NULL, -- should be varchar(10)
        this_is_nchar CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        this_is_nvarchar name(10) NOT NULL, -- should be varchar(10) 
        this_is_LongVarChar name NOT NULL, -- should be text
        this_is_LongNVarCHar name NOT NULL -- should be text
    )
```

Is there any JavaVM Parameter (or anything else, a workaround,...) which I can set for the PostgreSQL driver to correct this behaviour?